# Can I have one controller account from which I can handle/control the funds of multiple stash accounts?

Tags: account, stash

I have multiple stash accounts with funds which I will bond/stake but I would like to handle them from one controller account. Is that possible ? If yes, is it safe / recommended ?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot have one controller account to handle/control many stash accounts but you can use proxies to achieve that. Stash<>Controller is a strictly one-to-one relationship but proxies are many-to-many. So you can have N stashes with N controllers, and then set a single account as a [Staking proxy](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies#staking-proxies) for each controller.

For context, stash/controller existed before the Proxy pallet did. The stash/controller relationship is almost like a specific use case of a specialized proxy, the concept was just generalized into the Proxy pallet. We did discuss removing the stash/controller concept entirely and just telling people to use proxies, but it's still around basically for legacy reasons.

The use of proxies is encouraged and especially [proxies](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies#proxy-types) of a specific type/role, eg. governance proxy or staking proxy (so other than the type “Any”). A reason that we encourage the use of proxies is that they add a layer of security and organization to your accounts and account funds as mentioned in our educational video [What are Proxies?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuaM5dWAJis)